# Angular directive including <tr> creates "voodoo mode?"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that creates a row in a table that looks something like this:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('personRow', function() {
  return {
    template: "<tr><td>{{person.name}}</td><td>{{person.age}}</td></tr>"
  }
});
```

However when I try to use this directive with ng-repeat over a collection I get some very odd results -- Here is is in my page:

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>Looping wirth ng-repeat:</p>
    <table>
      <tr><td>foo</td></tr>
      <person-row ng-repeat="person in people"></person-row>
      <tr></tr>
   </table>
  </div>
```

Here's the output:

```
Looping with ng-repeat:

John32Mary45
foo
```

All the table elements seem to have been moved after the directive,  and on top of it somehow or other the "foo" row, which precedes the directive, is moved after it as well.

The generated html on the page looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="ng-scope">
  <p>Looping wirth ng-repeat:</p>
  <!-- ngRepeat: person in people --><person-row ng-repeat="person in people" class="ng-binding ng-scope">John32</person-row><!-- end ngRepeat: person in people --><person-row ng-repeat="person in people" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Mary45</person-row><!-- end ngRepeat: person in people --><table>
    <tbody><tr><td>foo</td></tr>

    <tr></tr>
   </tbody></table>
</div>
```

Can't figure out what's going on here...

Here's a plunker with the complete code that generates this:  [https://plnkr.co/edit/ia2Um68YF4OzWWsiIGKL?p=info](http://plunker%20code)

Answer (score 1):

A bit more research and found that this problem can be solved by using the directive as an attribute on the tr element rather than including the tr in the directive i.e. use

```
 <tr person-row>..</tr>
```

instead of

```
 <person-row></person-row>
```